# Как можно кастомизировать вывод ошибок в компоненте Битрикс sale.order.ajax?

Tags: javascript, битрикс

В стандартном компоненте sale.order.ajax ошибки выводятся в блок того раздела который пользователь заполняет, например если покупатель не заполнил свои данные то ошибки появятся в блоке Покупатель http://joxi.ru/KAg7BEJhgLyDxA . Как я понял основная часть логики работы компонента вынесена в JS в файл order_ajax.js

В моем случаи все блоки: Регион доставки, Покупатель и тд - это отдельные вкладки, http://joxi.ru/MAj7BRehvPNN0r и http://joxi.ru/ZrJOkEjH1jx71m . Когда покупатель переходит к последнему этапу  и нажимает кнопку Оформить заказ, в том случаи если он не заполнил сданные на первом этапе http://joxi.ru/MAj7BRehvPNN0r появляются ошибки но выводятся они на складке Покупатель, то есть чтобы их увидеть надо вернуться назад, это не удобно. Я хочу сделать специальный блок выше вкладок и в него буду выводится ошибки, чтобы они не были привязаны к вкладкам.  Но проблема в том что вывод ошибок жестко привязан к  разделам формы, которые у меня отображаются в виде вкладок.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы ошибки выводились в произвольный блок ? Как можно переопределить вывод ошибок через JS используя JS библиотеку Битрикс?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак в файле `order_ajax.js` проходят все проверки.
Подробнее по нужным функциям:

`showValidationResult: function(inputs, errors)` — Функция в которой полям с ошибкой добавляется класс hasError, который помечает ошибкой(в стандартном варианте добавляет обводку красным).

`showErrorTooltip: function(tooltipId, targetNode, text)` — Функция в которой добавляются тултипы для полей с ошибкой.

`showError: function(node, msg, border)` — Функция в которой выводятся ошибки в «групповой контейнер»

`refreshOrder: function(result)` — Функция в которой происходит разбор ошибок, которые приходят от сервера. Там есть ветка result.error

Первые 3 функции отвечают за валидацию на форме без перезагрузки, а четвёртая за обработку результатов от сервера.

Для Вашей задачи нужно переписать функцию `showError`. В эту функцию передаётся параметр `msg` — массив и в нём хранятся все ошибки, которые есть на форме.

Comment: Добрый день, столкнулся с проблемой, в кастомном шаблоне компонента каталог, на детальной странице каталога (шаблон catalog.element комплексного компонента catalog) товар не добавляется. Как я понял добавление товара в корзину из каталога где работает штатный ajax завязана на DOM дереве. Вопрос такой, если делать ajax-добавление на основе штатного JS Битрикса то нужно в верстке повторить все html-элементы, которые есть в штатном шаблоне? Можно каким то образом исключить часть DOM элементов из обязательных и указать только id-товаров, количество и цены?